# Python 3.6 - Can't convert Unicode in a string

Tags: python-3.x, unicode-string

I am doing some scraping work with Python 3.6 and retrieved some URLs in strings following this format:

```
someURL = 'http:\u002F\u002Fsomewebsite.com\u002Fsomefile.jpg'
```

I have been trying to convert the Unicode backslash (\u002F) in those strings in order to use the URLs (using regex methods, encode() on the strings, etc.), to no avail. The string still keeps the Unicode backslash and, if I pass it on to Requests' get(), for example, I am greeted by the following error message:

```
InvalidURL: Failed to parse: http:\u002F\u002Fsomewebsite.com\u002Fsomefile.jpg"
```

I searched for solutions in this forum and and others, but can't seem to put the finger on it. I am sure it is simple...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `codecs.decode` with the encoding named `'unicode-escape'`:

```
import codecs
print(codecs.decode(someURL, 'unicode-escape'))
# prints 'http://somewebsite.com/somefile.jpg'
```

Comment: this definitely works, thanks, @Blckknght! But can anyone clarify why this issue happens only in urls? If one just creates a string which includes this unicode character, like this:
`>>url_str = "https://someurl.com\u002Fv0.3\u002Fapplication"`
and prints it:
`>>print(url_str)`
the unicode chars are automatically decoded in the output:
`https://someurl.com/v0.3/application`
But it does not work in URLs when a web request is made?

Comment: That's a question of string literals. When you write your URL in a literal (that is, with quotation marks in your source code), the Python compiler is *immediately* translating the `\uXXXX` parts of the string into the corresponding characters (forward slashes, in this case). If you're reading it from a file or from some web content, you're actually getting the backslash-u-0-0-2-F characters, and the compiler doesn't reinterpret that, since it's data, not code. The best fix is probably to find why you're getting improperly formatted URLs from the source, rather than fixing it afterwards.